# Convert a NSDictionary value to a NSString

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

i want to convert the value of my dictionary into string. 
My code :

```
NSArray *keys=[services allKeys];
yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(146, (i*height_between_cells)+44, 40, 25)];
    NSString *nomber = (NSString *)[[services objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex: i]] objectForKey:@"Nomber"];
    //NSString *nomberService=[[services objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex: i]] objectForKey:@"Nomber"];
    [yourLabel setText:nomber];
    [recapView addSubview:yourLabel];
```

like you see i want to set the text of the label with my dictionnary value.
When i do that i have an error :

```
[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d57fd0
```

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Search your code and post the code for the part where you have sent a message named `length` . Where have you used that ?

Comment: @Unkn0wn.Bit they probably aren't calling length. Length will be getting called by something with another method that they haven't created. `NSString` uses length so `[[services objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex: i]] objectForKey:@"Nomber"];` more then likely returns an `NSNumber` then you pass it to `NSString` this will be where it's going wrong. If you know the the value is an `NSNumber` you could probably just add `stringValue` on the end.

Comment: Then he should use `[[[services objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex: i]] objectForKey:@"Nomber"] stringValue]` to set that NSString

Comment: I thought he may has made a mistake sending wrong message to an `NSNumber`, and he's making mistake that the code is aborted because of the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are assuming that the result of `[[services objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex: i]] objectForKey:@"Nomber"];` is giving you an `NSString` but it is in fact giving you an `NSNumber`.

Using a cast only makes the compiler happy. It doesn't actually convert anything.

Try something like this:

```
NSNumber *nomber = [[services objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex: i]] objectForKey:@"Nomber"];
[yourLabel setText:[nomber stringValue]];
```

Or using modern syntax you can do:

```
NSNumber *nomber = services[keys[i]][@"Number"];
yourLabel.text = [nomber stringValue];
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what i searched to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *nomberService=[[[services objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex: i]] objectForKey:@"Nomber"] stringValue];
```